# How do we find the cone angles of the conic sections that are the Newtonian orbits?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, planets

In planetary motion, when the eccentricity of a conic section and its semi-latus rectum are known, how do we find out the cone's semi-vertical angle and angle of cutting of the cone by plane?

Comment: This seems more of a mathematics than a physics question? Also - I think you can't find both the cone angle and angle of cutting from the values given - they are related (in other words, given the cone angle you should be able to find an angle and height of cutting for a given eccentricity and long axis). See [this earlier question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/114683/26969) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a hyperbola, the semi-vertical angle is half the angle between the asymptotes and the cutting angle of the cone is parallel to the axis of the cone. Otherwise, it's not unique. There's an infinite number of pairs of angles that would yield the same conic section.

Edit: Nevermind. You can get hyperbolas at more than one set of angles too.

Comment: Other hyperbolas form for less inclination to axis  of cutting plane (between zero and what takes to get a parabola).